# Can I prove that $\sqrt n\log{\sqrt n}=\Theta(n)$?

Tags: asymptotics

I'd like to  prove that $\sqrt n\log{\sqrt n}=\Theta(n)$ but I'm not sure how to do it.

This is my attempt:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log{\sqrt n}}{\sqrt n}=0 \Rightarrow \log{\sqrt n}=o(\sqrt n) \text{(Little o)}
$$

Therefore:
$$
\sqrt n\log{\sqrt n}=o(\sqrt n\cdot \sqrt n)=o(n)
$$
But this is too much as I need theta.

Comment: You can't prove it since it's not true.

Comment: "I calculated 1+1=2, but that's too much as I need 1" -- see the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt n \log\sqrt n}{n} = 0$$

Since this $\Theta(\sqrt n \log \sqrt n) = o(n) < \Theta(n)$.

Two functions $f(x), g(x)$ are asymptotically equal iff

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = c,\ c \in \mathbb{R},\ c > 0$$

Comment: but this is exactly what I wrote in my question

Comment: @Yos, no, you have divided $\log \sqrt n$ instead of $\sqrt n \log \sqrt n$.

Comment: but you're getting the same result I got, what does you answer contribute?

Comment: @Yos, yes, result is the same, because the statement itself is wrong. It would be correct if limit would be finite non-zero.

Comment: So you should say this explicitly in your answer. Otherwise you're just providing an almost identical calculation and identical result.

Comment: The limit f(x) / g(x) need not exist. For example f(n) = 2 + sin (n) = Theta(1), because 1 <= f (n) <= 3.

Comment: @gnasher729, yes, but limsup should exist, I think.